# Update time in linux and solaris machines from robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have obtained timestamp and have added 1 hour to current time . After obtaining the timestamp I need to update the time obtained in variable `${convertDateTime}` on linux or solaris machines. Please let me know if anyone has any idea on this ?

```
*** Variables ***
${currentDateTime}       ${EMPTY}
${convertDateTime}       ${EMPTY}


*** Settings ***
Library                   DateTime

*** Test Cases ***
Test001 - Test to check whether set of mails can be backed-up and restored incrementally
        ${currentDateTime}=              Get Current Date       exclude_millis=True
        Log             ${currentDateTime}
        #${convertDateTime}=             Convert Date                     ${currentDateTime}    result_format= %Y%m%d:%H%M%S
        #Log            ${convertDateTime}
        ${date} =       Add Time To Date        ${currentDateTime}      01:02:00:000
        Log     ${date}
        ${convertDateTime}=              Convert Date                     ${date}       result_format= %m%d%H%M%Y%S
        Log             ${convertDateTime}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set the system time from a test?

Comment: If you want to set the linux system time, use `SSHLibrary`  then simply execute a command like `date --set="STRING"` with parameter of the new sys date.

Comment: Do I need to set date `--set = "STRING"` in robot code after importing `SSHLibrary` ? Error is seen: - `No keyword with name 'date --set=' found.` Also in [SSHLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html) I do not see any `date --set` option present. Please let me know if am missing anything here ?

Comment: @BryanOakley, yes, please let me know if there is a way ?

Comment: The mentioned command (`date --set= "STRING"`) is supposed to be a Linux or Solaris command. In my Linux system the help for `date` says `... -s, --set=STRING          set time described by STRING ...`
You would use SSHLibrary to login to your servers and send the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking to move the system date by one hour. You can use the code below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Test Case ***

Run An Hour Faster

    ${stdout}=  run     date -Ins -s $(date -Ins -d '1 hour')
    Log To Console  ${stdout}
```

This should do. If you are looking to do it on remote machine use SSHLibrary and execute same command!

Hope it helps!